# R subset data frame by two vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and two integer vectors named `left` and `right`.

I want to create a subset of the data frame in such a way that that the numbers in the vectors will indicate the range of the columns to be included in the subset.

For example, for the nth row in the data frame, I want to keep the values 
`df[n,left[n]:right[n]`.
I tried doing so using `mapply()`:

```
aligned_rows<-apply(df,1,
                function(x) mapply(function(y,z)x[y:z], left, right))
```

But got an output that didn't make any sense.

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you are trying to achieve based solely on your description. Could you provide a simple example of data *before* and *after*? .... In particular, what you want to have as a result is not clear: a matrix, a list of vectors, a data.frame, something else?

Comment: Suppose I have a data frame    df<-as.data.frame(matrix(seq(10),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE);    left<-c(2,4);    right<-c(3,5);     I want to get a data frame such that:    subset<-rbind(as.numeric(a[1,left[1]:right[1]]),as.numeric(a[2,left[2]:right[2]]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command does the trick:

```
as.data.frame(t(mapply(function(x,y,z) df[x,y:z],
                       x=seq_len(nrow(df)),y=left,z=right)))
```

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(replicate(8,runif(4)))

#    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8
#  0.51  0.09  0.62  0.11  0.05  0.86  0.41  0.77
#  0.31  0.23  0.43  0.60  0.26  0.62  0.71  0.36
#  0.43  0.28  0.65  0.36  0.40  0.78  0.84  0.54
#  0.69  0.27  0.57  0.43  0.84  0.36  0.24  0.09
```

Applying

```
left <- c(1,3,5,7)
right <- c(2,4,6,8)
as.data.frame(t(mapply(function(x,y,z) df[x,y:z],
                       x=seq_len(nrow(df)),y=left,z=right)))
```

yields

```
#    X1    X2
#  0.51  0.09
#  0.43  0.60
#  0.40  0.78
#  0.24  0.09
```

In order for that to work, each range defined by `left` and `right` must contain the same number of elements. Furthermore, both `left` and `right` must contain as many elements as there are rows in `df`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned problem is not clear, hope below example will give some hints:

```
#dummy data
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(20,1,50),nrow=4))

#right left dummy
right <- c(1,3,4)
left <- c(5,4,5)

#nth value, also try n <- c(2,4) to get 2nd and 4th rows
n <- 2

#return list of data.frames
lapply(1:length(right),
       function(x) df[n,right[x]:left[x]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, your problem is ill-posed, because there's no guarantee that the number of items you want in each row will be the same. Remember that a data frame is a rectangular object, ie all the rows must have the same length.

What would be more reasonable to obtain is a *list*, which doesn't have this restriction:

```
mapply(function(l, r) df[, l:r], left, right, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Assuming this results in the same number of items per row, you can then combine them with `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, mapply(function(l, r) df[, l:r], left, right, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

There are other issues, eg you're potentially combining items from different columns together which would be nonsensical if they have different classes. But you haven't mentioned this as a problem, so I'm going to assume that your data frame is really more akin to a matrix for which this kind of manipulation is more sensible.